# BASH - catching errors

Tags: bash

How can I have a script react to an error being thrown? Equivalent to Java's `try` and `catch`, but for BASH.

So, something like:

```
<Some Command>
if <Some Command> throws error
    #Do Something
else
    #Do Something Else
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command returns exit code after it is executed.  `$?` variable will have the exit status of last executed command. 
If this variable has value other than zero then command threw error.

```
 <command>
 if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
       echo error
 else echo no error
 fi
```

Comment: Thank you! what if more than one error is thrown? Is this possible?

Comment: You can assign the `$?` to any another variable for future purpose. Eg. `ERR=$0`

Comment: that makes sense. And it also makes sense that no two errors can be thrown at the same time. Does `$?` have a technical name?

Comment: I am not aware of any name of this variable.